# A complex analytic version of the eigencurve

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms, moduli-spaces, langlands-conjectures

I am very much a beginner to the theory of eigencurves so there might be many mistakes in what follows, especially since it is all very speculative.

My understanding of the eigencurve $\mathcal C_{N,p}$ (of Coleman and Mazur) is that it is a rigid analytic family that parametrizes and interpolates p-adically the classical eigenforms of level $Np$. There is a map to weight space $\mathcal C_{N,p} \to \mathcal W_{N,p} = \text{Hom}_{\text{cont}}(\mathbb Z_p^\times,\mathbb C_p^\times)$.

Moreover, the points should give rise to Galois representations, as ordinary forms do.

This is supposed to be an extension of the naive family of Eisenstein series (by Serre/Swinnerton-Dyer?):
$$E^*_{k} = \frac{(1-p^{k-1})\zeta(1-k)}{2} + \sum_{n\geq 1}\sigma_{k-1}(n)q^n$$
where we use the p-adic analytic continuation of the zeta function to define the above for $k \in \mathbb Z_p$.

Now, I read in this [paper](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/papers/families.pdf) of Buzzard the idea that one could also define a complex analytic family of Eisenstein series by just letting $k$ vary over complex numbers in the above formula instead:
$$E_{k}(q) = \frac{\zeta(1-k)}{2} + \sum_{n\geq 1}\big(\sum_{d|n}d^{k-1}\big)q^n.$$

**Question:** Is it also possible to find a complex analytic interpolation or parametrization of the eigenforms (fixing level), analogous to the eigencurve?

In the case of $GL_1$ over $\mathbb Q$, we want to interpolate Dirichlet characters of fixed level (=period). In the p-adic case, by class field theory, the space we should look are characters from $\mathbb Z_p^\times \to \mathbb C_p^\times$ for $p$ not dividing the level which is a one-dimensional family.

So the complex analogue should also probably be one dimensional and an obvious analogue would be the set of all functions from $(\mathbb Z/N)^\times \to \mathbb C^\times$.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like nt.number-theory (added now).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that convention but it makes sense.

Comment: This won't work. $\mathbf{Z}$ is discrete in $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$ and that kills off the hope for any meaningful notion of family -- there's no meaningful way for two cusp forms of different weights can be "close" to one another. Just another one of the many ways that the nonarchimedean world is richer and nicer than the archimedean one.

Comment: I guess you are assuming that classical forms have to be dense in the the moduli space?

Comment: There are actually interesting examples of p-adic eigenvarieties in which classical points are not dense. However, the non-density "means something", in the following sense: there's a Zariski-dense set of points in weight space such that the fibre of the eigenvariety over weight space has a classical interpretation; the fact that almost all of those fibres are actually empty is telling you some deep non-obvious global property of the relevant automorphic forms space.

Comment: (cont'd) If you try to do this in the real-analytic world, then because cusp-forms only make sense for integer weights and the integers are discrete, then either your parameter space will be 0-dimensional and convey no geometric information, or classical points will be *boringly* non-dense in the parameter space -- boringly non-dense because it wouldn't be meaningful for it to be any other way.